# react native run android failing how to fix it

Tags: react-native

How to fix this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
 Could not generate a proxy class for class com.android.build.gradle.tasks.BuildArtifactReportTask.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
```

Comment: This looks like a straight  copy-paste of an error you got.  Add code, what you are trying to do, ...